# AdminBAL Class Information

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hello I found some code online and while going over it I came across Dim admin As New AdminBAL() . What is adminBAL? The code is originally in C# and I converted it to vb. I can't find much about it. And how do I access it?
where I found code: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article180.aspx

```
    Private Sub BindCurrentUsers()
    Dim admin As New AdminBAL()
    Try
        GridView1.DataSource = admin.LoadAll()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ee As Exception
        ' lblError.Text = ThrowError.LogAndThrowError(ee)
    Finally
        admin = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer is: Who knows? My best guess is that it's a custom class used by the author which isn't included with the code example. BAL is a common acronym for "Business Access Layer" which is where code specific to the business/app is put. AdminBAL therefore suggests a class that handles the specific business logic for admin in this application. Voting to close as this is very localised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says

> I have taken an example of a simple database table of having UserName,
>   Password, SuperPassword, UserType, Admin Desc and Active fields. For
>   simplicity reason I shall not show the database manipulation code
>   here.

AdminBAL is the DAO for this database table, and if you look closely he uses just

```
GridView1.DataSource = admin.LoadAll();
```

and

```
new AdminBAL().Insert(u.Text, p.Text, sp.Text, dT.SelectedValue, ad.Text, 
                      bool.Parse(dA.SelectedValue));
```

ie, just two methods with names that make it very clear what they do.  Should be simple enough to come up with an alternative tailored to your data storage...